# I want to break from for loop in swift

Tags: swift, for-loop

Here is my sample code:

```
var items = ["a","b","c","d"]

for i in items{
    if(i == "e"){
        print("first break")
        break
    }else{
        if(i == "b"){
            print("second break")
            break
        }else{
            print("work")
        }
    }

}
```

I want to exit from for loop and don't want to execute print("work") and want to stop the loop when the condition is true.

Output:

> work
>   second break

desire output:

> second break

Comment: Your code is working fine. It is exiting the `for` loop once the value of `i` is `"b"`.

Comment: my desire out put is just "second break", it is possible?

Comment: Sure, remove the `print("work")` line.

Comment: no, no. I have to check the condition like this that's why. The reason of using for is cuz items can be change

Comment: Sorry but you are not clearly explaining what you want.

Comment: What I want is if i is equals to letters "e" or "b", then break don't want to execute print("work"). And print "work" at one time when i is not equal to letters "e" or "b".

Comment: That's what your code is doing. It breaks when the letter is "e" or "b" and it prints "work" for the other letters.

Comment: yeah. there is a way to stop the loop after the condition is true? and don't want to execute for other letters.

Comment: That is what your code is doing. `break` stops the loop.

Comment: we are misunderstanding each other. seem like you don't understand what I mean

Comment: I understand fine. Your code works exactly as you are describing. Your code exits the `for` loop when the letter is "e" or "b". That is what you have stated over and over that you want. There is no problem. If you want different behavior then please [edit] your question so your issue is clear. You need to better describe the behavior that you want compared to what it is currently doing.

Comment: just edited the post.

Comment: OK, now we are back to my 2nd comment. Simply remove the `print("work")` line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks everyone for answering. I had found a solution.

```
    var items = ["a","b","c","d"]

    if(items.contains("e")){
        print("first break")
    }else{
        if(items.contains("b")){
            print("second break")
        }else{
            print("work")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The first letter your loop hits is “a”. This causes “work” to print. Since there is no `break` after that `print...` statement, the `for` moves onto the “b”, printing “second break”.

If you want to break after “work”, you need to add the missing `break` line...

Comment: I just want to break from the loop and don't want to execute print("work"). Adding break after "work" also print "work". That's why

Comment: Well, you’ve told it to break after it sees letters “e” and “b”.  If you want it to break elsewhere, you’re going to have to add a break statement at the appropriate point.

Comment: yeah. That's I am asking